# What is the minimum cardinality for a set intersecting each member of a configurations of pairwise intersecting disks of the same radius?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

Consider, in the euclidean plane, some configuration of (closed) disks of the same radius such that each pair of disks has a non-empty intersection.

What is the minimum of the cardinalities of subsets (of points) of the plane that intersect *every* disk (for a generic configuration of the above form)?

Of course for some specific configuration it could be $1$, or if each $3$ out of $4$ intersect, I believe the answer is $13$, but I need an answer for such a configuration in general.

Comment: What do you mean by "points covering circles"?

Comment: Incomprehensible.

Comment: @mrf oh my bad. It means that the point should lie on the circle/disk. If it is inside or on the the circle/disk then it means the point is covering the circle.

Comment: @GerryMyerson how? there should be a proof.

Comment: I guess you should start with a definition of “circle intersection setting”. Since “all circles” without additional information would mean all the circles in the plane, you can't expect a finite number of points to cover these. So what is the set of all circles, how is it parametrized or described?

Comment: @MvG yes all circles in the plane. Like if I have N lines in the plane and every pair of these lines intersects then I need atleast N/2 points to cover(I have defined it in comments). These circle lies on the plane such that you pick two circles and they will will intersect or meet atleast at 1 point. It is the "setting". Every pair of the circle intersects atleast at 1 point.

Comment: Do you mean that the points should *lie in all the regions formed by intersection of circles?*

Comment: @Tim yep or inside the circles.

Comment: Please, Ammar, edit the body of your question so that it is possible to figure out what you mean. As currently written, it is incomprehensible.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Tim has given the answer? I have clearly stated what I want to ask. Gerry please mention what part of my question you are not able to understand.

Comment: I don't think the answer given by @Tim matches the question you are trying to ask (although I can't be sure, since your question is incomprehensible). I think the question you are trying to ask is, given a set of unit circles in the plane such that each pair of circles has a nonempty intersection, how many points do you need to guarantee that each circle contains at least one of them. If that is your question, then please edit the body of your question so it says so. If you succeed in clarifying your question, I'll vote to reopen it. If it gets reopened, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes it is what I am asking. I will edit my question and thanks.

Comment: It still has that confusing opening sentence. "Each circle have a nonempty intersection" is gibberish – one circle can't have an intersection, an intersection has to be with something. Question still needs work.

Comment: @GerryMyerson okay I know that the set of points of circle should have a intersection. But thats what you said in your comment.

Comment: I don't know what "the set of points of circle should have an intersection" means. And note that in my comment, I wrote, "each **PAIR** of circles has a nonempty intersection."

Comment: @GerryMyerson edited.

Comment: I rewrote this completely. Please check if it still matches your intent.

Comment: @quid yeah thats what I meant. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 3. It's proved on page 144 of [Danzer, Grunbaum, and Klee](http://math.rice.edu/~andyp/teaching/2013SpringMath366/DanzerGruenbaumKlee.pdf), Helly's Theorem and its relatives, Proc. Sympos. Pure Math. 7 (1963) 101-180, and cited in [Chakerian and Stein](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-01/S0002-9939-1967-0206818-3/S0002-9939-1967-0206818-3.pdf), Some intersection properties of convex bodies, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 18 (1967) 109-112.

Here's how it's stated in Chakerian and Stein: let $h(K)$ be the least cardinal $r$ such that whenever $F$ is any family of pairwise intersecting translates of $K$, there exist $r$ points such that each member of $F$ contains at least one of them. ...if $C$ is a circular disk, then $h(C)=3$.

I think both papers are freely available on the web.

Comment: Well there is no proof in the cited papers. It is just stated. I can't find any proof in referred papers.

Comment: I think it's there in the Danzer et al. paper, it's just that you have to dig through the notation and the definitions and the generality of the situations they treat. Anyway, you said you needed the answer – you didn't say you needed the proof. Why do you need the proof?

Comment: you are doing math here. If you claim something you have to prove that its right and by the way you should have cited the original work which have the proof. Thanks by the way for referring papers. I am a student I am picking up things so I needed the proof because i need to know how it is possible and why?

Comment: Here are some more papers that might be worth a look. I haven't looked to see whether they are available on the web. Danzer, Zur Losung des Gallaischen Problems uber Kreisscheiben in der Euklidischen Ebene, Studia Scientiarum Mathematicarum Hungarica 21 (1986) 111-134. Grunbaum, On intersections of similar sets, Portugaliae Mathematica 18 (1959) 155-164. Karasev, Transversals for families of translates of a two-dimensional convex compact set, Discrete and Computational Geometry 24 (2000) 345-353.

Comment: The Grunbaum paper is available on the web, and does have a proof, and also a reference to a proof in Hadwiger and Debrunner, Ausgewahlte Einzelprobleme der kombinatorischen Geometrie in der Ebene, Enseignement mathematique (2) 1 (1955) 56-89. You can get to the Grunbaum article from https://eudml.org/doc/114819

Comment: The Hadwiger-Debrunner work is available in English translation as part of  Combinatorial Geometry in the Plane, Holt, Rinehart and Winston, New York 1964.

Answer (score 1):

I get the following series:

$$1, \ \ \  n=1 \\
3, \ \ \  n=2 \\
7, \ \ \  n=3 \\
13, \ \ \  n=4 \\
21, \ \ \  n=5 \\
31, \ \ \  n=6 \\
$$

On examining, the generating function is $\boxed {n^2 -n+1}$

---

For showing this, you'll need principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Yeah but how? Like is it for same radius circles(unit circles) or for all?  I was asking for unit circles.